# How to check if all inputs in a table are ng-valid using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, validation

I have a table, where each row has a input field. See code below.

Upon clicking on save, I'd like to iterate over all the inputs and check if they're ng-valid.

```
<div class="line" data-ng-repeat="data in datas">
    <div class="..." style="width: 30%">
        <form name="dataForm">
            <input name="aliasName"
                   type="text"
                   focus-me
                   ng-model="data.something"
                   ng-pattern="/^[A-Z|a-z]+[\-|A-Z|a-z|0-9]*$/"
                   ng-required="true"
                   ng-maxlength="63"
                   tabindex="1">
            </input>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- Next columns -->
</div>
```

For example, if one of the input fields is empty, it is `ng-invalid`.

So, **how do Iterate over all the inputs to check if any of them is `ng-invalid`?** Thanks.

The only thing that worked for me is iterating over the dom and checking the class for `ng-invalid`. The downfall is that it is not the NG's way - if AngularJS decide to change their DOM manipulation to a different way, my hack won't work.

Comment: You should create a custom validation directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you wrap a form field with any angular type validation (like ng-required or ng-pattern) and the field value doesn't meet the validation - the model value will remain undefined.
So, you can just iterate the model list, and see which model value is undefined.

Hopes it helps!

Answer (score 2):

> you can use ng-disabled , so your button will be disabled if even one field was invalid

```
<button ng-disabled="dataForm.$invalid" >save</button>
```